# In python/selenium, how can I get the contend in HTML code

Tags: python, selenium

In python/selenium, how can I get the sku number in HTML code as in image?
Blow code only can get text of the element, I want the content directly in the HTML. Thanks!

[image]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&qrst=1&wq=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&stock=1&pvid=b86735ca93754d6f96a68a4ee0e187d5&psort=3&click=0')

driver.execute_script("""
(function () {
var y = 0;
var step = 100;
window.scroll(0, 0);
function f() {
if (y < document.body.scrollHeight) {
y += step;
window.scroll(0, y);
setTimeout(f, 100);
} else {
window.scroll(0, 0);
document.title += "scroll-done";
}
}
setTimeout(f, 1000);
})();
""")
print("下拉中...")
# time.sleep(180)
while True:
    if "scroll-done" in driver.title:
        break
    else:
        print("还没有拉到最底端...")
        time.sleep(3)
skus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='J_goodsList']")
for sku in skus:
    print(sku.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any element attribute value with `.get_attribute` method.
So, here you can do something like the following:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&qrst=1&wq=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&stock=1&pvid=b86735ca93754d6f96a68a4ee0e187d5&psort=3&click=0')

driver.execute_script("""
(function () {
var y = 0;
var step = 100;
window.scroll(0, 0);
function f() {
if (y < document.body.scrollHeight) {
y += step;
window.scroll(0, y);
setTimeout(f, 100);
} else {
window.scroll(0, 0);
document.title += "scroll-done";
}
}
setTimeout(f, 1000);
})();
""")
print("下拉中...")
# time.sleep(180)
while True:
    if "scroll-done" in driver.title:
        break
    else:
        print("还没有拉到最底端...")
        time.sleep(3)
skus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='J_goodsList']//li[@data-sku]")
for sku in skus:
    print(sku.get_attribute("data-sku"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the  code feedback None

Comment: You possibly missing a delay. Try putting a sleep before `skus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='J_goodsList']")` and let me know if that helped. If yes - we will improve that to remove hardcoded sleep

Comment: //div[@id='J_goodsList']/ul/li shouldn't you guys be targetting the li's

Comment: @Prophet  it's ok now after adding sleep time after skus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='J_goodsList']"). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm happy I could help you! In case this resolved your problem please accept the answer to indicate the question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. Instead of targetting the ancestor `<div>` canonically you can target the descendant *`<li>`*. Finally, instad of extracting the *text*, you need to *`get_attribute("data-sku")`*

---

### Solution

To extract and print the ***sku numbers*** e.g. *3313643*, *5327144*, etc you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&qrst=1&wq=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&stock=1&pvid=b86735ca93754d6f96a68a4ee0e187d5&psort=3&click=0')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("data-sku") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#J_goodsList ul li")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&qrst=1&wq=%E6%9E%9C%E6%B1%81&stock=1&pvid=b86735ca93754d6f96a68a4ee0e187d5&psort=3&click=0')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("data-sku") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='J_goodsList']//ul//li")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['3313643', '5327144', '1256816', '3127041', '100007725801', '7153462', '100020544789', '3088504', '2439951', '4602877', '100013213444', '100018630091', '10028327196597', '100005772043', '3081867', '1044735', '4323156', '100010085943', '848890', '100010783078', '4377126', '3557308', '5417682', '100020805609', '4641871', '100017615158', '100032110985', '848893', '100013210524', '100017615166']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```